# How to search string within larger string excluding certain values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a field with a large string - an nvarchar field containing code. I have a query to search for a string using LIKE '%CustomField15% within the field of code and it works as one would expect.

However, when I use LIKE '%CustomField1%' I also get results for 'CustomField11', 'CustomField12', 'CustomField13' and so on.

How can I just return 'CustomField1' without any of the other values?

I do sometimes want to search for CustomField15 or any other value so I can't eliminate it always. Sometimes it's CustomField2 or CustomField22 and so on. Basically, I need a solution for when the search string is just CustomField1, 2 or 3.

```
DECLARE @Field AS nvarchar(25) = 'CustomField1';
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Code LIKE '%'+@Field+'%';
```

EDIT: To answer a couple of the initial questions: There can be lots of code before or after the field name being searched. It's complete code and I'm searching for fields being used in the stored code anywhere. The field name may or may not have a space after it as it depends on how the person who wrote the code being searched tends to write code.

Super-simple example of searching for a field in pseudo-code stored in a table:

```
UPDATE table
SET CustomField1= CustomField2 + [Salary]
WHERE [CustomField1] > 100000
```

If I search for CustomField1 with a space at the end, I won't get any results. A person may use brackets or operators without space. Another might as if I were searching for the CustomField2 in this example.

As it is now, I can return this row but still have to weed through results that contain 'CustomField11', 12, 13, etc when I search for 'CustomField1'.

Comment: Does anything follow the field name? If, for example you have a trailing space or comma, you could use `%CustomField1 %` (notice the space before the second %) or  `%CustomField1,%`. (comma before the second %).

Comment: Can you give some representative examples of what the "code" field can look like?